# Will objects that go beyond the cosmological event horizon eventually vanish from sight?

Tags: cosmology

Suppose a galaxy is headed beyond the cosmological event horizon. Photons it emits now will eventually reach us, but there is a point at which photons will no longer be able to reach us.

Supposing that a finite number of photons are emitted, this would seem to imply that the galaxy will eventually vanish from sight. But my understanding is that instead we would see the galaxy asymptotically slow down as we see more and more redshifted light from it. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Sources that say that the light is redshifted into the indefinite future are talking about classical cosmology and not considering quantum effects.

Quantum mechanically, as you say, the galaxy emits only finitely many photons before crossing the horizon and so there should be a last photon – although I should qualify that in a couple of ways. First, unless you know all future measurement outcomes, the disappearance still takes forever in the sense that you can never be sure that you've seen the last photon; another one could arrive at an arbitrarily late time. Second, even if you do know all future measurement outcomes, the horizon emits Hawking/Unruh radiation, and because of boson indistinguishability I'm not sure that there's any way even in principle to unambiguously identify the last galaxy photon amidst that noise.

Comment: This thorough answer seems consistent with the claim by Davis (of the Lineweaver & Davis pair that designed the very widely-used diagram showing some cosmological horizons in relation to the Hubble sphere) that particles which were visible before reaching the outer surface of our observable region might disappear upon their passsage of that surface, but reappear (due to the expansion of our space) after reaching it.  I'd appreciate any pointing out of whatever misapperception I might have on that possibility.

Comment: Part of my previous comment hinges on the fact that the speed of light limits relative motion, but not spatial expansion, which can accelerate to an unlimited extent:  I've gotten into some arguments about that fact.